# Does fuse/FIS support spark-rest?

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am using FIS2.0 and find the following unsupported comments:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html-single/fuse_integration_services_2.0_for_openshift/#get-started-s2i-binary

```
Unsupported Starter Modules

The following components do not have a starter because of compatibility issues: 

...
camel-spark-rest
...
```

While I am using spark-rest component in fuse rest DSL on EAP, now I need to migrate it to OCP, I tested the spark-rest with rest DSL on FIS running with spring boot, found no error, does it mean I can use camel-spark-rest on FIS? what the risk could be.

My sample camel-context.xml in FIS is:

```
<restConfiguration component="spark-rest" port="9091"/>
<rest id="_rest_prj1" path="/prj1">
    <post consumes="text/xml" id="_rest_prj1_svc1"
        produces="text/xml" uri="/svc1/a1">
        <to uri="seda:preprocessor"/>
    </post>
</rest>
```

Best regards

Lan

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spark-rest but you won't have RH support in case of anything happening with that component.